# FabricJS not render SVG correct when SVG include text with custom font?

Tags: html5-canvas, fabricjs, fabricjs2, node-canvas

I have a problem with render SVG in fabricjs when SVG include text with custom font.
[image]

How to make SVG in Fabricjs display correct with custom font?

Here is my code:

```js
var canvasObject = document.getElementById("editorCanvas");

  // set canvas equal size with div
  $(canvasObject).width($("#canvasContainer").width());
  $(canvasObject).height($("#canvasContainer").height());

var canvas = new fabric.Canvas('editorCanvas', {
  backgroundColor: null,
  selectionLineWidth: 2,
  width: $("#canvasContainer").width(),
  height: $("#canvasContainer").height()
});

var imageObj = new fabric.Image();
  canvas.add(imageObj); 
imageObj.setSrc('https://futushigame.firebaseapp.com/group_test.svg', function(imageObject) {
  imageObject.set({top: 0, left: 0});
  imageObject.set('dirty', true);
  canvas.renderAll();
  setObjectCoords();
});


function setObjectCoords() {
  canvas.forEachObject(function(object) {
  object.setCoords();
  });
}
```

```css
#canvasContainer {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.js"></script>
 <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fabric.js/2.4.3/fabric.js"></script>
  
  <style>
   @font-face {
                font-family: 'CurlzMT';
                src: url("https://futushigame.firebaseapp.com/CurlzMT.ttf") format("ttf");
                font-weight: 'normal';
                font-style: 'normal';
            }
 </style>
  
  <div id="canvasContainer">
    <canvas id="editorCanvas"></canvas>
  </div>
```

Here is my resources: 
1. Font file: [CurlzMT](http://futushigame.firebaseapp.com/CurlzMT.ttf)
2. SVG file: [group_test.svg](http://futushigame.firebaseapp.com/group_test.svg)

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to embed the font in svg file.
The content of the svg must be like this 
https://files.fm/f/qhvbe8jj

Comment: How did you embed font in svg?
I am using google fonts https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Pacifico
and don't know how to embed it in exported svg by fabricjs
Can you help me with it?

Comment: Check this: https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/5162/how-do-i-embed-google-web-fonts-into-an-svg

Comment: @MariusTurcu seems like the file link is broken can you please fix it and update the answer.

Comment: Please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer